# Rails SendGrid Email From Development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendgrid

We use SendGrid in a production app and it works fine. We were recently trying to test a new feature/email in development however and cannot seem to get an email to send. Any idea where we're going wrong? We are using similar features to production and we also followed SendGrid's implementation guide. Feels like I'm missing something simple!

First I exported the `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` and for kicks added it to my `.bash_profile`

```
export SENDGRID_USERNAME=xxxxxxx
export SENDGRID_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

I've confirmed in the console that these exist and are correct.

Created a `developer_email.html.erb` file:

```
<p>Hi! Sendgrid test</p>
```

And a `DeveloperMailer` file:

```
class DeveloperMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "tom@xxxxxx.com"

  def developer_email(developer_id)
    @recipients = ["tom@xxxxxx.com"] 
    mail(to: @recipients, subject: 'Does sendgrid work?')
  end
end
```

Updated the `development.rb` file:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port:                 '587',
  domain:               'localhost:3000',
  user_name:            ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password:             ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  authentication:       :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

When I go to send the email in the console, it acts like it sent, but the email never actually arrives:

DeveloperMailer.developer_email(1) #to send the email. Seems to work:

```
2.3.1 :001 > DeveloperMailer.developer_email(1)
  Rendered developer_mailer/developer_email.html.erb (1.5ms)

DeveloperMailer#developer_email: processed outbound mail in 133.3ms
 => #<Mail::Message:70263824429080, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: tom@xxxxx.com>, <To: ["tom@xxxx.com"]>, <Subject: Does SendGrid Work?>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>> 

#But I never get anything sent to my email
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

**EDIT**

Updated development.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password:             ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  authentication:       :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Still no email though.

Comment: Hello Tom,

Have you find any solution for above question?
if yes then please post your answer if possible because I face same issue

Comment: So I definitely got it to work. But all of my code looks the same as above. Unfortunately it's been a few years since I touched it and can't remember what I did. It might have been a setting I had to change in sendgrid itself. I'd explore there, especially on the activity link posted below by bwest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do telnet by following commands

```
telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 2525
```

If you get proper response from SMTP Service then change `SMTP port from 587 to 2525`

In my case "587 port" is not responding

After changing the port it works for me

Answer (score 0):

`domain` in this context is an SMTP `HELO` domain, not the actual environment's domain. Change it to the same domain you use in your SendGrid profile and don't specify a port and give it a try.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your SendGrid activity at https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity?

Comment: Nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to verify the sender email or domain of the sender email before you can send an email with SendGrid. See https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/sender-verification/ and https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/#domain-authentication